# String index out of range oracle bi publisher

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, bi-publisher, oracle-apex-18.2, oracle-bi

I'm download .xml from **Oracle apex > Shared Components > Report Queries** and open with oracle BI addon in MS Word. XML is successful loaded I'm add header text and change column name and save as .RTF file.

After import .RTF file in **Oracle apex > Shared Components > Report Layouts**. When try test report get error
***String index out of range: -1***

Any solution for this problem.

Comment: Hello, do you still need help with this? Where are you seeing this error? Are you able to capture more detail?